# How to use eagerload.order in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to ordinate the result of a consult where the controller are using:

```
> @fair_items = FairItem.to_show.last_30_days.eagerload.order(:start_date)
```

Now, the results are showing in ascendent mode, I need the inverse, in descendent mode. I has tried to use :desc after :start_date, but not works.

If can you help me, one day, I will pay a beer for you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `order(start_date: :desc)` or `order('start_date DESC')`

Please note the colon (:) after start_date on the first one.

Comment: in my case, ('start_date desc') work. Many thanks for the help! I owe a beer!